# Response header date, always there?

Tags: date, header, response

I writing a client application that can communicate with a server and i need to know the current server time (to see if the client time is different).

I´m wondering. Is the response header "Date" always available?

Comment: Please give us a clearer view of the whole situation. What OS is on that server ? What application server is serving your requests ? What levels of access do you have on that server ?

Comment: No access level. Just HTTP requests. Any webbserver. Any OS.

Comment: And this is because the server owner can remove the date response?

Comment: The server owner or the application developer.